# I'm looking for sites with static pages xml with http header

Tags: hosting, web-hosting

It's kinda weird question, but i think here you have big experiences with many websites. As in topic i'm looking for websites which allow me to create for example correct version of json or xml, like wordpress.com/custom-page.html

Comment: What do you mean by correct version of JSON or XML? There is no such thing as that, do you mean valid JSON or XML?

Comment: not a raw text, but valid xml

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard to guess what you want, try https://www.freeformatter.com

It has validator for both XML and JSON, also formatter and other stuff. But generating valid JSON and XML is not something arbitrary. You should read their definition. {} is a valid JSON, and  is a valid XML.

Comment: you may find its CSV to JSON/XML convertor useful too!